# GCC template errors

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I'm trying to port a C++ project to iOS. It compiles just fine in QtCreator on Linux and Windows and also on MSVC.
Now on Xcode/GCC, with a certain templated class I get the following error: "error: too few template-parameter-lists".

The code that causes this error looks something like this:

```
template <typename TA, typename TB, int Type>
class MyClassImpl
{
public:
   MyClassImpl();
   virtual int GetType() const
   {
       return type;
   }
};    

typedef MyClassImpl<float, int, 12> MyFloatIntClass;

MyFloatIntClass::MyFloatIntClass()
{
...
}

int MyFloatIntClass::GetType() const
{
   return 22;
}
```

I'm guessing that something about the typedef syntax is illegal and GCC is more strict on the standard.
Can anybody tell me what exactly the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: If this is a copy/paste of your real code, you are missing a `;` after the class before `typedef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess, but do you need to add template<>?

Since it's a template specialization, I believe it still needs to be a template.

ex.

```
template<>
MyFloatIntClass::MyClassImpl() {}

template<>
int MyFloatIntClass::GetType() const {
    return 22;
}
```

EDIT:  From modelnine's answer- turns out it needs the untypedef'd name for the ctor.

EDIT2:  The following code works fine for me:

```
template <typename TA, typename TB, int Type>
class MyClassImpl
{
public:
   MyClassImpl();
   MyClassImpl(const MyClassImpl<TA, TB, Type>&);
   virtual int GetType() const
   {
       return Type;
   }
   const MyClassImpl<TA, TB, Type>& operator=(const MyClassImpl<TA, TB, Type>&);
};    

typedef MyClassImpl<float, int, 12> MyFloatIntClass;

template<>
MyFloatIntClass::MyClassImpl()
{
 //
}

template<>
MyFloatIntClass::MyClassImpl( const MyFloatIntClass& rhs )
{
 //
}

template<>
const MyFloatIntClass& MyFloatIntClass::operator=( const MyFloatIntClass& rhs )
{
  return *this;
}

template<>
int MyFloatIntClass::GetType() const
{
   return 22;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but that definitely makes it worse. I think if I add template<>, the compiler thinks I want to define yet another template.

Comment: see modelnine's answer- it's better than mine.

Comment: @iOSPorter: Do those copy ctors work for you?  You need to fully specify the type of rhs to be of MyClassImpl<TA, TB, Type> or you'll need a double template.

Answer (score 4):

As you're defining full specializations of methods of the respective class, you'll still need to prefix the definitions with `template <>`, which is the "template-parameter-lists" you're missing. Furthermore, the constructor must be named as the class is, so `MyFloatIntClass::MyFloatIntClass()` is illegal (as `MyFloatIntClass` is just an alias, not a class name). The following compiles fine for me (g++ 4.5.3):

```
template <typename TA, typename TB, int Type>
class MyClassImpl
{
public:
   MyClassImpl();
   virtual int GetType() const
   {
       return Type;
   }
};    

typedef MyClassImpl<float, int, 12> MyFloatIntClass;

template <>
MyFloatIntClass::MyClassImpl()
{
}

template <>
int MyFloatIntClass::GetType() const
{
   return 22;
}
```

Comment: That kind of works, thanks! But: not for all cases. I've also got a copy constructor and an operator= and I don't know how to handle them. I'll update the example source code for you to see. bear with me.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I still have some other problems with this templates class, but I guess I will open another issue for them. Thank you very much!